# Ubi-partman failed with exit code 141 error when installing Kubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partitioning, kubuntu

I constantly get this error when attempting to install Kubuntu from USB. I have tried multiple versions of Kubuntu (14.04, 16.04), multiple USBs, but I still get this issue. Has anyone encountered this problem? I haven't found a solution yet. Help is much appreciated